# Does Java System Class shared between processes? 

Tags: java, android

I have a question regarding the Java language: in android

i tried changing a System.property X inside process A, then activating process B

(i thought maybe it's initializing all the System.properties again)

(process B didn't see the changed System.property X as expected),

then i resumed the first process and saw that the changed System.property is still there.

I know that the System class can't be instantiated. since this is the case,

i thought that it will be shared among all the processes.

yet this is not the case.

i understand why we want this to happen, but how can this be if System class is not instantiated? what mechanism in Java causes this behavior?

thanks for the help

Comment: Can't say anything specifically about the Android environment (which is a bit non-standard), but in a standard Java environment there is no shared addressability between separate system processes.  On most systems each "process" has its own address space, disjoint from any other process's address space, so no sharing is possible.  `System` can't be instantiated because Java defines it that way, not because of any sort of sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what mechanism in Java causes this behavior?

While the `System` class **bytecode** is shared among Dalvik VM processes, any singleton **data** that might be held by the `System` class (or any other Android OS Java class) is not shared among Dalvik VM processes. Rather, such objects are instantiated on the local process' heap, no different than any other objects.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, do you have any idea where can i find it in the android source code?

Comment: where a Dalvik VM process is initialized and the "such objects are instantiated on the local process' heap" happens...

Comment: @nir: No, I do not know where you can find that in the source code.

Comment: well.thanks anyway i will try to find it somewhere in the Dalvik libraries. if i will find it i will post here again where it is.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, Android keeps your activities around until it decides it needs resources for something else. So when you *"resumed the first process and saw that the changed `System.property` is still there"* you might have as well gotten the very state you'd left, as if you were switching windows on your desktop.